# Copy object to another object of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
xxx = $("div");
yyy = xxx;
```

However everytime I remove/add an element to `xxx` it also gets removed/added to `yyy`. I understand that this is expected cause when dealing with objects, JS will not copy by value, but by reference. So I tried a few methods I found on Google to copy by reference the jQuery selector but nothing works.

Maybe jQuery selector works a little different in order to be able to copy them? So how would you do this? I know I can do `yyy = $("div")` instead of `yyy = xxx` but I got curious about this thing and how to solve it!

One interesting point, is that if I use the code below it should work, but no, it does not work. For some reason jQuery does not "like" what I did below.

```
yyy = [];

for (i=0;i<xxx.length;i++) {
    yyy.push(xxx[i]);
}
```

Any suggestions and insights on how the above code does not work? I mean, if I try to use `yyy` variable to change css styles or anything like `yyy.css({display:"none"})` it does not work.

**EDIT
After reading all your comments/answers I think something is not clear (probably I was the guilty one). I want to have 2 variables referencing the same elements (initially) and later I want to manipulate those 2 variables independetly, maybe remove an element from one variable, add another element to the other variable...
So, cloning would not be correct because I would not be referencing the DOM node anymore in the `yyy` variable. If I have a node in the `xxx` variable I want the same node to be referenced at `yyy` variable, I dont want to clone the node and lose the reference to the original node.

When you clone a set of matched elements in jQuery, you lose reference to the original elements! And I need to keep that reference!
**

Comment: It is not a copy it is just a reference to it. Clone it. https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: would `yyy = xxx.clone()` help?

Comment: You are not making a copy with the for loop, it is still the same references to the objects.

Comment: Can you please show an example of how you're removing / adding elements to `xxx`?

Comment: I'm still confused about this _adding_ and _removing_. I'm not aware of any jQuery methods that allow you to do so that don't create new instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using [.slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/). This should break the reference

```js
const xxx = $("div")
const yyy = xxx.slice(0)
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I needed! None of the other answer, for some reason, got it right. Maybe I was not asking it right, but you nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

Use the clone method.
This will create a copy the element, not copying it's reference.

https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Doesn't `.clone()` create copies of all the elements?

Comment: @Phil is that not what the OP wanted?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's actually pretty unclear what OP wants but I don't think they want to make copies of the elements. I get the feeling they just want the two `jQuery` objects `xxx` and `yyy` to not be the same reference. It would be a lot clearer if they explained how they're _"removing/adding"_ elements

Comment: Please see my edit, I cant clone because cloning loses the reference to the original element. If one DOM element is in the `xxx` variable, I also want to have this exactly same reference in the `yyy` variable in such a way that if I change the CSS property of this DOM, I can change it using the `yyy` variabl or `xxx`. But I want `xxx` and `yyy` to have different elements assigned later. Initially they are referencing the same elements but later I may want to add/remove one element from `xxx` without affecting `yyy`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to break the reference, I would create an exact new element with the exact `outerHTML`:

```js
let xxx = $("#test");
let yyy = $(xxx[0].outerHTML);

xxx.append("Hello");    // Only append to xxx

yyy.append("Good bye"); // Only append to yyy

console.log(xxx.html());

console.log(yyy.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Now you will be working with two identical elements. Only difference is that one of them is appended on the DOM (`xxx`) and the other is not appended (`yyy`).

---

#### Differences with .clone() method

Since they are different objects by reference, all data appended to one element would modify the other:

```js
var xxx = $("#test");
var yyy = xxx.clone();

xxx.append("Hello");
yyy.append("Good bye");

console.log(xxx.html());
console.log(yyy.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">Hello</div>
```

Comment: What's the benefit of doing this instead of using `.clone()`?

Comment: Well, actually I was bad in my explanation. It does not copy by reference, they are 2 different elements in the DOM. But if you append data to one element, it would append the same to the other, so thery are still related.

Comment: Please see my edit, I cant clone because cloning loses the reference to the original element. If one DOM element is in the `xxx` variable, I also want to have this exactly same reference in the `yyy` variable in such a way that if I change the CSS property of this DOM, I can change it using the `yyy` variabl or `xxx`. But I want `xxx` and `yyy` to have different elements assigned later. Initially they are referencing the same elements but later I may want to add/remove one element from `xxx` without affecting `yyy`.